# Convert columns to rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a sql server database table which has data like this.

```
No  Age Qty Remove
01  2   350 20
02  1   255 5
```

But I want Output like this

```
          01    02
Age        2    1
Qty      350    255
Remove    20    5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). At least give a try before asking!!

Answer (score 1):

Use unpivot and pivot. I hope you can use this:

```
DECLARE @t table(No char(2), Age int, Qty int, [Remove] int)
INSERT @t values('01',  2,   350, 20),('02',  1,   255, 5)

SELECT Cols, [01], [02]
FROM  
(
  SELECT Cols, No, val
  FROM @t as p  
  UNPIVOT      
  (val FOR Cols IN           
  ([Age],[Qty],[Remove] )) AS unpvt  
) p
PIVOT (max(val) FOR [No] IN ([01], [02])) AS pvt
```

Result:

```
Cols   01   02
Age    2    1
Qty    350  255
Remove 20   5
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. it was helpful me to create query dynamically.